# how to give foreign key contraints when records came from many table

Tags: mysql

I am using Java swing with mysql database.

As per my requirements I have one JComboxBox which has values from 3 parent table. I dont know how to give foreign key on it.

I have 3 tables CMaster, SMaster, GMaster and that 3 table has different no of columns. I want to provide CName, SName and GName values to JComboBox.

Can any one please suggest me?

Answer (score 0):

Every parent table must be having a Common Column in Your JComboxBox.. So refer this column for Foreign Key in Your Table..

Comment: No, Actually parent table not having common column. I have edited my quetion please check again